# Preciso fazer uma função em javascript que calcula um valor maior que outro, mas estou com dificuldade

Tags: javascript

Eu preciso que o quando o valor do segundo deposito for maior que o primeiro ele de uma resposta positiva, senão de uma mensagem de erro. Porém em todos os testes o código apresenta a mensagem de erro.

```
const form = document.getElementById('form-valida');
const valorOne = Number(document.getElementById('valor-one').value);
const valorTwo = Number(document.getElementById('valor-two').value);

function validar(valorOne, valorTwo) {
return valorTwo > valorOne;
}

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    let formValida
    e.preventDefault();

    const mensagemSucesso = `Você enviou os valores: ${valorOne} e ${valorTwo} com sucesso`;
    const mensagemErro = `O valor do segundo depósito deve ser maior que o primeiro!`;

    formValida = validar(valorOne, valorTwo)

    if (formValida) {
        const containerMensagemSucesso = document.querySelector('.success-mesage');
        containerMensagemSucesso.innerHTML = mensagemSucesso;
        containerMensagemSucesso.style.display = 'block';

        valorOne =' ';
        valorTwo =' ';

    } else {
        const containerMensagemErro = document.querySelector('.success-mesage');
        containerMensagemErro.innerHTML = mensagemErro;
        containerMensagemErro.style.display = 'block';
        
    }
   
})
```

Comment: já tentou mover as constantes para dentro da função do submit? os valores precisam ser lidos no momento do submit e não antes

Comment: Muitoooooo obrigado meu amigo, eu tinha revisado tudo menos isso. valeu mesmo.

Answer (score -2):

Tem que ler os valores após o preenchimento.

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form-valida');

function validar(valorOne, valorTwo) {
  return valorTwo > valorOne;
}

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const valorOne = Number(document.getElementById('valor-one').value);
  const valorTwo = Number(document.getElementById('valor-two').value);

  const mensagemSucesso = `Você enviou os valores: ${valorOne} e ${valorTwo} com sucesso`;
  const mensagemErro = `O valor do segundo depósito deve ser maior que o primeiro!`;

  const formValida = validar(valorOne, valorTwo);

  const containerMensagem = document.querySelector('.success-message');

  if (formValida) {
    containerMensagem.innerHTML = mensagemSucesso;
  } else {
    containerMensagem.innerHTML = mensagemErro;
  }

  containerMensagem.style.display = 'block';

  // Limpa os campos após a validação
  document.getElementById('valor-one').value = '';
  document.getElementById('valor-two').value = '';
});
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado.